# How to return json string from server

Tags: c#, json

I want return correct json structure from my server.
I tried this, but in response I had a string:

```
string jsonDataStructure = "[{\"Field1\": 1, \"Fieald2\":true}, {\"Field1\": 1, \"Fieald2\":true}]";

return new JObject(
            new JProperty("MyData", jsonDataStructure)                                                
);
```

How can I get my JSON data with a write data structure?

Comment: Something seems off to me. Why do you want to add a string containing encoded json data to a json property? This would json-encode the string again, thus you would end up with something that is json-encoded twice. Instead of adding the jsonDataStructure string to the json property "MyData", add the actual data object (not Json-encoded) to "MyData"...

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context? what exactly is the server? Is it a simple Http server? Is it a TCP server? Is it a asp.net/ asp.net core webapp?

Comment: elgonzo, I have only string like this, i need to send it for debugging

Comment: Himanshu Pant, it is simple asp.net server

Comment: Where is that string coming from? How did you get that string?

Comment: from previous working code version:)

Comment: No ;-) That was not the intention of my question :-) That json string has to be generated by "something". Where/how is this json string being generated? If i understand your last comment correctly, there should be something in your code that actually creates that json string. That piece of code generates the json string based on some existing data. Instead of getting a json string from that other code there, get the data directly.

Comment: Oh, i understand. It's old respond from server, wich got this data from db and parsed it. Now DB broken. I just want to chek my UI and hoped this is simpliest way

Comment: Ah, i see. That's a bit unfortunate. I guess then a quick&simple way could be what @HimanshuPant is outlining in their answer (taking the comments underneath the answer also into account)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit :- If your string is a serialization of an object say jsonResponse, you would do

```
return Ok(jsonResponse)
```

. However if it is a string you would do

```
return Ok(JObject.Parse(jsonDataStructure))
```

. That should solve your problem.

First of all, I couldn't really get the gist of this question, so I'm going to say change your return statement to this.

```
return JObject.Parse(jsonDataStructure);
```

Comment: tried this, but got error: "Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object". Maybe something wrong in my data? It's big object.

Comment: I looked at the data you've given as an example, it's actually a JArray not JObject, that's why my initial comment was to provide a bit more context.

Comment: Omh, you are right! I'm trying to parse object instead of array ..! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to send an object, I would recommend serializing it using libraries like "newtonsoft.json". If not, you may also wrap the data you want to send in an object and still use the library

Comment: The code snippet in the question using JObject and JsonProperty is a pretty strong indication of the asker is already using Newtonsoft.Json.